# How to change the values of dictionary from string to int if they are in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, casting, typeerror

I have a dictionary as

`maketh = {'n':['1', '2', '3'], 'g': ['0', '5', '6', '9'], 'ca': ['4', '8', '1', '5', '9', '0']}`

which I intend to change to

`maketh_new = {'n':[1, 2, 3], 'g': [0, 5, 6, 9], 'ca': [4, 8, 1, 5, 9, 0]}`

The order in which the numbers are in the values are very important. So, the order should remain the same
even after they are changed.

The error I always get when I try to change it using any method available online is:

`TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'`

"If there is any typing mistake pls ignore it..."

One that I wrote on my own thinking that may be something like this can work was:

```
maketh_new = dict()

for (key, values) in maketh.items():
    for find in len(values):
        maketh_new [key] = int(values[find])
```

I tried it thinking if I can access all the elements of the values that are in the list as a string then I may be able to type caste it into int.  But I get an error as:

```
'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

So if someone can help me find a solution, please do it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming all elements in the values are digits, you can `map` `int` on the values:

```
maketh_new = {k: list(map(int, v)) for k, v in maketh.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'n': [1, 2, 3], 'g': [0, 5, 6, 9], 'ca': [4, 8, 1, 5, 9, 0]}
```

If not, you can use `str.isdigit` for safer typing:

```
maketh = {'n':['1', '2', 'a'],  # Note 'a' at last
          'g': ['0', '5', '6', '9'], 
          'ca': ['4', '8', '1', '5', '9', '0']}

maketh_new = {k: [int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in v] for k, v in maketh.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'n': [1, 2, 'a'], 'g': [0, 5, 6, 9], 'ca': [4, 8, 1, 5, 9, 0]}
```

Comment: Is there no better way to do this? I have faced this problem so many times and it annoys me to no end having to type `int(x)` everywhere or run such a list comprehension on it

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _better_. Do you want a dict whose string is always evaluated (when possible) into integer?

Comment: I mean a single function without using a for loop at all (internally it may be the same, but ideally it should convert to the best numerical data type and even look for errors). Something in the standard library.

Comment: Hmm.. to the best of knowledge, i would say [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) is the closest. But it's a very big library for type casting purpose only.

Comment: Thanks, it has actually helped me a lot...now type casting the integers while getting in csv file won't be that big of a problem